# .NET TreeView causes application to crash when trying to check Parent node

Tags: c#, treeview, crash, parent

I have a TreeView  with check boxes, and when a user checks a child node, I want to go up the tree and check each parent.  However, for some reason my application blows up whenever I touch the parent node.  For the nodes in my tree, I've extended TreeNode to create my own objects with some data that I need to store in them, but I still reference them as TreeNodes when checking/unchecking.  My code looks like this:

```
//checkBox checked event handler
    if (node.Parent != null)
    {
        checkAllParents(node.Parent);
    }
//

private void checkAllParents(TreeNode node)
{
    node.Checked = true;
    if (node.Parent != null)
    {
       checkAllParents(node.Parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: how about some Exception text?

Comment: There is no such thing as a C# TreeView. What is the full name of the TreeView class you are referring to?

Comment: print out some trace info. You may have a circular reference somewhere.

Comment: I've got a try/catch in my program, but it still crashes without catching an exception.

@John - yes, there is a TreeView in .NET - System.Windows.Forms.TreeView

Comment: @alexD John is nitpicking, but he _is_ correct; there is a class called TreeView that is available in .Net, but it is _not_ related to C# at all (other than that it can be used in C#). He was just making sure you're using the one that's available in .Net; there are **many** more available implementations in the wild.

Comment: ah.  Just wanted to make clear the language I was using..i just assumed the rest was implied

Comment: @Kai...is there an easy way to root out a circular reference?  I'm creating the tree from an XML file, and just by eyeballing my code  I can't see anything that jumps out at me.  However, I am adding the nodes to both the TreeView and a List<>, but I don't think I'm creating a circular reference anywhere with that.

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: ^^as I said, there is no exception, it just crashes.

Comment: How about having it perform a Console.WriteLine (or log, or whatever) each time a node is hit (for example, have it print the node text value). That way you can tell what it's doing before it crashes.

Comment: What members did you override in your custom TreeNode class ?

Comment: @Michael...I took out the recursion and just tried checking only the first parent and it still crashed on that...the reference is all screwed up.

@Thomas - I didn't override anything.  Should I have?

Comment: @alexD, on the first line of checkAllParents method, add "Debug.Writeline(node.Text);", check the output see if that's what you expected.

Comment: @alexD: first, I'm nitpicking because there are several TreeView controls in the .NET Framework, and they can all be used from _any_ .NET language, not just C#. You'd just as well call them the VB.NET TreeView controls. Also, there are at least 3 "TreeView" controls in the .NET Framework: `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView`, `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView`, and `System.Windows.Controls.TreeView`. You should update your question to say which one you're using so readers don't have to read the comments to know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  It wasn't a circular reference but it was most certainly circular in nature.  This was a big dumb mistake on my part..in the event handler I was using recursion to check DOWN the tree as well...I implemented this a while ago and didn't really think about it, so when I added another piece of recursion to check up the tree I ended up with an infinite loop between the recursion function and the event handler (which was getting called every time the recursive function checked one of the nodes..the After_checked event).  Bah.

Comment: So you took your stack overflow to StackOverflow?

Comment: Naturally=)

Oh and my fix was to remove the event handler when I entered the handler function, perform the recursion, then add the event handler back at the end of the handler function.  Works perfect now.

Comment: +1 for posting your answer. I suggest you click the checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a infinite recursion that is blowing the stack (a stack overflow no less).  node.Parent must never be evaluating to null.  It won't be caught in a try catch because your code isn't throwing an exception, you are just causing a stack overflow and it is the .net frameworkthat throw the exception.  You will also be triggering the recursion multiple times, every time you set node.Checked = true; you will fire of the event handler again but you also call check all parents again, i would remove the recursive call to check all parents and just set the node to checked, the event handler will do the recursion for you.

Comment: I took out the recursion and just had it do the first Parent node and it still crashes.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger, how many times is it called? does it crash on the first call?  What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a circular reference then you would get a stack overflow, which cannot be caught. Try to modify your code to get rid of the recursion:

```
// checkBox checked event handler
checkAllParents(node);

private void checkAllParents(TreeNode node)
{
  var parent = node.Parent;
  while (parent != null) {
  {
    parent.Checked = true;
    parent = parent.Parent;
  }
}
```

If app enters an infinite loop then you do have a circular reference. You could further modify the code to catch circular references:

```
private void checkAllParents(TreeNode node)
{
  var parent = node.Parent;
  var visitedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
  while (parent != null)
  {
    if (visitedNodes.Contains(parent))
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Circular reference!");
    visitedNodes.Add(parent);
    parent.Checked = true;
    parent = parent.Parent;
  }
}
```

Of course this is not the right place to handle circular references. But if it helps..